# Custom Iterator is slow

Tags: java, performance, iterator

I've been trying to measure the performance of my custom iterator over a simple int array. It really is simple, as shown below:

```
class IntArrayIterator_NoCheck implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private final int[] array;
    private int counter = 0;

    public IntArrayIterator_NoCheck( int[] array ) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return counter < array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return array[counter++];
    }

}
```

After comparing it to ArrayList iterator and Trove (http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), I found strange results. The testing was performed in the following way:

- List/array of 100000 random int elements
- WarmUp

  - 10000x iterating over whole collection
  - 10000x iterating over whole collection again
- Test

  - 10000x iterating over whole collection, measuring via System.nanoTime AND ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime()

The Trove TIntArrayList iterator is the fastest one with 30 ms runtime. Java ArrayList iterator had 85 ms runtime. The custom iterator over simple int array had 320 ms runtime!

What is the possible reason for the horrible performance of my custom iterator? After reviewing ArrayList and TIntArrayList iterator implementations, they are much more complex (performing more operations), therfore I do not understand why is it faster. Could anybody, please, explain this to me?

Comment: Don't write benchmarking code like this manually, use JMH: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `next` method will produce the same bytecode as

```
public Integer next() {
    return Integer.valueOf(array[counter++]);
}
```

Note that for any `int` outside the range of the cached values (only guarantied to be `-128` to `127`) a new `Integer` object is created.

This does not happen for `ArrayList`, since the conversion happens before storing the `Integer`s in the list.
[`TArrayList`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html) has [a custom iterator type](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/iterator/TIntIterator.html) that returns the primitive type `int`, which does not require the creation of a `Integer` object.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that at all.

Answer (score 3):

You have an iterator of *Integer* there, but you are using an array of *int*.

Thus you do constant unboxing when iterating. You know; turning Integer into ints and back is a costly operation; and doing that for each iteration **is** killing you.

As each and any call to **next** means boxing an int into Integer.